# If and only if there is a bijection from a set onto itself, then the set is of distinct terms?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals, multisets

Is it true that iff CardA = Card A then A is a set of distinct terms?

[This questions is actually from a confusion on what a set versus multiset is]

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you asking whether $|A|=|A|$ if and only if $A$ is a set of distinct terms? And what do you mean by '$A$ is a set of distinct terms'?

Comment: Yes. A is a set of distinct terms if no terms are repeating. E.g. we don't have assume A={1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4}.  There is no bijection from A to A because let $x_n$ denote the nth term of A. $f(x_4) = f(x_5)$  and $x_4 \neq x_5$. I mean value wise $x_4$ = $x_5$ however in terms of place or position, $x_4$ denoting the 4th term is not the same as the 5th term or $x_5$. Terms are named by their place in a sequence. A is not not injective . $\mathbb{N}$ is a set of distinct terms. @Bram28

Comment: Sets never have repeating elements.  The example you just gave would be called a 'multiset' or a 'bag', but not a set. So, for sets, both sides of the if and only if are true for *any* set: for *any* set $A$: $|A|=|A|$, and $A$ does not have repeating elements. So, the if and only if is true because both sides are always true.

Comment: So I can't make a set containing all the real numbers? If I tried it'd be something like {0,.99999999999999repeating, 1...} oops, we can't have repeats and .9999999repeating =1, so then I'd have to make this a bag for it to work so [0,.999999999999repeating, 1....]? So there is no set containing all the real numbers but there is a bag containing all the real numbers because sets can't have repeats and the reals are full of repeats?

Comment: As you know, 0.9999... = 1, meaning that 0.999... and 1 are really just different *representations* of the same number. So: I *can* have a set with all real numbers: once I put 1 in there, I have thereby put in the same number that 0.9999... represents, so I am not missing anything there. And I can *also* have a set with all decimal representations of all real numbers ... in *that* set 0.999... and 1  are regarded as different elements, so it is ok to put both of them in *that* set.

Comment: so {.5, 1/2, 25/50} is a set but {.5, .5} is not a set but rather a multiset? Does {.5, 1/2, 25/50} have any repeating elements? @Bram28

Comment: According to wikipedia,  First, in an extensional definition, a set member can be listed two or more times, for example, {11, 6, 6}. However, per extensionality, two definitions of sets which differ only in that one of the definitions lists set members multiple times, define, in fact, the same set. Hence, the set {11, 6, 6} is exactly identical to the set {11, 6}. The second important point is that the order in which the elements of a set are listed is irrelevant (unlike for a sequence or tuple). We can illustrate these two important points with an example:
{6, 11} = {11, 6} = {11, 6, 6, 11}.

Comment: If we are talking about sets of *representations* of numbers, then $\{.5, \frac{1}{2} \}$ is a set, but it is *not* a set of numbers, because it has repeats of the same number. Or: following the Wikedia example: it would be a set with 1 element, since $\{ .5, \frac{1}{2} \} = \{.5 \} = \{ \frac{1}{2} \}$

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a set it is defined to have no duplicate elements.  Because Card $A$ = Card $A$ is a tautology, your statement is of the form True iff $A$ is a set of distinct terms.  As long as $A$ is a set this will be true.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your question is:

Is it true that for any set $A$: $|A|=|A|$ if and only if $A$ is a set of distinct elements?

Well, *sets* *never* have repeating elements.  So, for sets, both sides of the if and only if are true for *any* set: for *any* set $A$: $|A|=|A|$, and $A$ does not have repeating elements. So, the statement is true since  both sides of the if and only if are true for any set $A$.

But, if we do allow sets to have repeating elements, i.e. if this question is really about *multisets*, rather than *sets*, then the statement is false: It is still true for any multiset $A$ that $|A|=|A|$, but clearly a multiset $A$ can contain repeating elements.

Comment: Wikipedia: First, in an extensional definition, a set member can be listed two or more times, for example, {11, 6, 6}. However, per extensionality, two definitions of sets which differ only in that one of the definitions lists set members multiple times, define, in fact, the same set. Hence, the set {11, 6, 6} is exactly identical to the set {11, 6}. The second important point is that the order in which the elements of a set are listed is irrelevant (unlike for a sequence or tuple). We can illustrate these two important points with an example:
{6, 11} = {11, 6} = {11, 6, 6, 11}.

Comment: Right. So, since $\{ 6,11 \}$ does not have repeating elements, $\{ 6,6,11 \}$ does not have any repeating elemets either ... It's just written in a way that makes it look like it does. Put differently, if we are talking about sets, then $\{6,6,11\}=\{ 6,11 \}$, but if we are talking about multisets, then $\{6,6,11\} \not = \{ 6,11 \}$

Comment: sequences can repeat but sets can't repeat?

Comment: @brittany That's right. One big difference between sequences and sets is that sequences are ordered, and sets are not.